# how to send file in json with other data in node js

Tags: java, json, node.js, multipartform-data, multipart

I am working on some module where I am stuck with this question.
I am using request module in node js. I have many example but they just sends only the file(not in json).
I have working code in Java. Just trying how to do the same in node js

```
    String json = "{ \"values\" : { ";
    json += "\"Field1\" : \"xyz\", ";
    json += "\"Field2\" : \"abc\", ";
    json += "\"File Name\" : \"sample.jpg\"";
    json += " } }";

    // build the multipart entity
    HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
            .addTextBody("entry", json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .addBinaryBody("File 2", new File(filename))
            .build();
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: File with extension  json or anything else?

Comment: It is a txt file

Comment: Thenf read it using npm fs module, with utf8 and send the value to like:
{
"file1":"text file data"
}

Comment: Use:
const fs.  = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./Index.text', 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
  });

Comment: Actually I want to this as an attachment. Because I am calling some third party app where it is only accepted as a attachment.

Comment: You're wanting to construct a `multipart/form-data` response. In node.js, you'll probably want to use a package [like this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) do do this. (or make your own). Also, as an aside in node you will probably want to build your JSON differently, using `JSON.stringify`